# F# query expression and C# LINQ with Array.Contains fail after migration to .NET8

Tags: c#, sql, f#, .net-8.0, query-expressions

Recently I've migrated my code to .NET8 and some of my queries stopped working.
Here's an example, which used to work in .NET7

```ml
let accounts: Array[] = ...

query {
    for user in db.User do
      where accounts.Contains user.Account
      select user
  }
```

I get an error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 
'[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.InlineQueryRootExpression]' could not be translated. 
Additional information: Empty collections are not supported as inline query roots. Either 
rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation 
explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 
'ToListAsync'.
```

I noticed that now the expression doesn't like empty arrays and it fails when `accounts` doesn't contain any items. So I need to add a guard everywhere, e.g.

```ml
let accounts: Array[] = ...

// This works just fine
query {
    for user in db.User do
      where (accounts.Length <> 0 && accounts.Contains user.Account)
      select user
  }
```

The only problem is that in my codebase I use the `.Contains` method many, many times. Do I really need to add the part `accounts.Length <> 0 &&` eeverywhere or maybe there's something better I could do?

I use SQL Server 2022.

Comment: There is an open issue about this: [Did Contains stop working on empty list in EF Core 8? #32375](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32375).  It has been fixed in the EF Core main branch, see [Allow empty inline collections (#32414)](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/01a470c83c019c3280ac3e350bfe42ecdd647374), but is still present in the [8.0.0 branch of `RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v8.0.0/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs#L386).

Comment: On Nov 27, [roji commented](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32375#issuecomment-1827340977): *Reopening to consider servicing.*  So that's where things stand.  You might want to comment on the open issue to ask for a servicing fix in EF Core 8 and/or to ask whether there is an easier workaround that checking `array.Length = 0` everywhere.

Comment: Does that answer your question? [ajcvickers](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32375#event-11108502780) added Servicing-approved and the 8.0.2 milestone to the issue on Nov 30, 2023 so it seems like a fix in in the pipeline for [EF Core 8.0.2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/milestone/186).

Comment: Yes, it's good. Thanks. You can post it as an answer, so that I can approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open issue about this: [Did Contains stop working on empty list in EF Core 8? #32375](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32375) with [minimal repo](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32375#issuecomment-1826916744)  by [roji](https://github.com/roji)

> Minimal repro is any composing on top of an empty inline array:
>
> ```
> _ = ctx.Blogs.Where(b => new int[] { }.Contains(b.Id)).ToList();
> ```

It has been fixed in the EF Core main branch, see [Allow empty inline collections (#32414)](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/01a470c83c019c3280ac3e350bfe42ecdd647374), but is still present in the [8.0.0 branch of `RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v8.0.0/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs#L386).
On Nov 30, 2023 the fix was [approved](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32375#event-1110850278) for inclusion in servicing release [EF Core 8.0.2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/milestone/186).

So you could either wait for the 8.0.2 servicing release of EF Core or, if you cannot wait, use the `accounts.Length <> 0 && ...` workaround.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in my initial post. The right walkaround is `accounts.Length <> 0 &&` , not `accounts.Length = 0 ||`. I've already modified my question. Sorry for this.

Comment: Upgrade to 8.0.2 solved this issue for us.